# reading input, then writing to file

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I am trying to write out a matrix to a .txt file using 4 modules the modules are:

1. input.f90 reads input from a .txt file
2. navierstokes_loser.f90 creates the matrix (I will add some do loops here but, first I just need it to print)
3. resultatplot.f90 take in the matrix from navierstokes_loser then prints it to   .txt file
4. main.f90 combines all the modules and runs the program

When I run the program I get Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

What am I doing wrong?

**input.f90**

```
 module input

implicit none

contains


subroutine lesinput(n,omega)

!Output
integer :: n
real(8) :: omega


!Åpner fil og gir variable verdier
open(1, file='input.txt',status='old',action='read')

read(1,*), n
read(1,*), omega


close(1)

end subroutine lesinput



end module input
```

**navierstokes_loser.f90**

```
module navierstokes_loser


implicit none

contains


subroutine los_navier(n,omega,u)

!input
integer :: n
real(8) :: omega


!lokal
real(8) :: u(n+1,n+1)
integer :: i,j


u(n+1,n+1)=0.0d0


end subroutine los_navier

end module navierstokes_loser
```

**resultatplot.f90**

```
module resultatplot

implicit none

contains


subroutine vektorplot(n,u)

!input
integer :: n
real(8) :: u(n+1,n+1)

!lokale
integer :: i,j
real(8) :: vek_x


!Skriver vektor verdier til fil som gnuplot skal bruke
open(2,access='sequential',file='vekdata.txt',status='unknown')

write(2,*)'# x y vx vy'

 do i=1,n+1
    do j=1,n+1

    vek_x=u(j,i)


    write(2,*) i, j, vek_x

    end do
write(2,*)''
end do

close(2,status='keep')


end subroutine vektorplot


end module resultatplot
```

**main.f90**

```
program main

use input
use navierstokes_loser
use resultatplot

implicit none

integer :: n
real(8) :: omega
real(8), dimension (:,:), allocatable :: u

call lesinput(n,omega)

allocate(u(n+1,n+1))

call los_navier(n,omega,u)


call vektorplot(n,u)


end program main
```

Comment: You can try step by step. First just read the input to make sure you are doing it right. The add the computation of the matrix, make sure it works well up to that point then add the printing of the matrix to file. It is not very wise to wait for people to do everything.

Comment: It reads the input correctly, both in the main.f90 and in the navierstokes_loser.f90, but when i add the matrix u it bugs.

Comment: So my problem is storing the matrix u, and then passing it to vektorplot

Comment: I made some changes in main.f90 and navierstokes_loser.f90, now the code compiles, but it prints some weird numbers, that is not correct. It prints a matrix in correct size though( n+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I see quite a few things here:

1. Units smaller than 10 -- that's always dangerous. Best: When `open`ing files, use `newunit=<somevar>` and then use this `<somevar>` as the unit for reading, writing, and closing. But at least use numbers larger than 10, and not 1 and 2.
2. Let's talk about `u`:

   1. In `main.f90`, it is an allocatable, 1-D array, but in `los_navier` it's a 2-D array.
   2. It is never actually allocated.
3. Clearly indicating `intent` in subroutines helps the compiler find bugs early.

So, without further ado, here's my suggestion:

```
module input
    implicit none
contains
    subroutine lesinput(n,omega)
        integer :: n
        real(8) :: omega
        integer :: read_unit
        open(newunit=read_unit, file='input.txt',status='old',action='read')
        read(read_unit,*), n
        read(read_unit,*), omega
        close(read_unit)
    end subroutine lesinput
end module input

module navierstokes_loser
    implicit none
contains
    subroutine los_navier(n,omega,u)
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        real(8), intent(in) :: omega
        real(8), allocatable, intent(out) :: u(:,:)
        integer :: i,j
        if (allocated(u)) deallocate(u)
        allocate(u(n+1, n+1))
        u=0.0d0
    end subroutine los_navier
end module navierstokes_loser

module resultatplot
    implicit none
contains
    subroutine vektorplot(n,u)
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        real(8), intent(in) :: u(n+1,n+1)
        integer :: i,j
        integer :: write_unit
        open(newunit=write_unit,access='sequential',file='vekdata.txt',status='unknown')
        write(write_unit,*)'# x y vx vy'
        do i=1,n+1
            do j=1,n+1
                write(write_unit,*) i, j, u(j, i)
            end do
            write(write_unit,*)''
        end do
        close(write_unit,status='keep')
    end subroutine vektorplot
end module resultatplot

program main
    use input
    use navierstokes_loser
    use resultatplot
    implicit none
    integer :: n
    real(8) :: omega
    real(8), dimension (:, :), allocatable :: u
    call lesinput(n,omega)
    call los_navier(n,omega,u)
    call vektorplot(n,u)
end program main
```

Comment: Better quickly factor out that real kind value, or VladimirF will get cranky.

Comment: Probably, but there were already too many issues with this code.

Comment: If it is already in the original code, I am not that picky. I leave it there sometimes myself.

Comment: Thank you chw21, it worked! Whats the problem with real(8)? Dosent it mean you get more accurate numbers?

Comment: The problem is that this isn't really a standard. More often than not, it'll work, but there's no guarantee. For better alternatives, see here: http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Real+precision